# Why is it that my text is inside my table when my TR is not filled with any TD or TH tags?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

If I were to create only tr tags inside a table and input texts without any TD/TH tags inside, the texts will appear outside the table as shown in the example codes below. You can also run code snippet to see what I mean.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<table border="1">

<tr>
data1
</tr>
<tr>
data2
</tr>
<tr>
data3
</tr>

</table></body>
</html>
```

However, why is it that when I use XML/XSL to display a table exactly like how I would display it above, the data is automatically inserted into the table rows like this picture below

[image]

Below are my XML and XSL codes:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>

<test123 >
 <person >
 <firstName>John</firstName>
 <lastName>Smith</lastName>
 <mobile>0211223344</mobile>
 </person>
 <person>
 <firstName>Mary</firstName>
 <lastName>Jane</lastName>
 <mobile>0244556677</mobile>
 </person>
</test123>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
 <xsl:template match="/test123">
 <html>

<body>


<table border="1" >
  <xsl:for-each select="person">

<tr>
  <xsl:value-of select="firstName" />
</tr>

  </xsl:for-each>

</table>

  </body>

 </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You should try changing the `xsl:output` method to "html" as that might cause different behaviour. But, in any case, the HTML specification says you should have either `th` or `td` as a child of the `tr`, so you shouldn't really get too worried about what happens when you omit then, as you should not be omitting then in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: You do not "use XML/XSL to display a table". You use a browser to display the HTML code produced by the XSL transformation. How the browser displays an incomplete table code is up to the browser. Nothing to do with XSLT: you'll get the same result if you write the same HTML code by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing td|th to generate cell of the table so you must have to place data inside td or td element for creating proper placement of data in cell. Run snippet for reference:

And same you can edit XSLT code by updating for each section see below code for your reference:

```
<xsl:for-each select="person">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="firstName" />
                </td>
            </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry if i am not being clear. The thing is even without <td> or <th> tags, i am able to generate table cells with just <tr> tags on my XML document. This is what is puzzling me.